# Webpack Sourcemap speed issue

Tags: webpack, sass

I am implementing Webpack to bundle up all my projects assets. It is going well but as I have linked files such as images being referenced from my `.scss` files I need to have sourcemaps enabled in order for `resolve-css-loader` to sort out the files and place them correctly. The sourcemap generation is KILLING the bundle compile speed so much.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can speed it up in anyway?

My webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'js': './app/assets/scripts/application.js',
    'css': './app/assets/styles/application.scss'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'assets'),
    filename: '[name]/application.js',
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  },
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=svg/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]'
      }
      // {
      //   test: /\.css$/,
      //   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      //     use: 'css-loader'
      //   })
      // }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]/application.css')
  ]
};
```

Also, I have set watch to true but it doesn;t seem to be picking up any file changes at all. Why could this be?

I'd be grateful if anyone can help me out with my config here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using webpack 2 or 3. So try setting [`devtool`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) to

`devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',`

Plus you should only need to use `extract-text-webpack-plugin` when doing a production build, not needed while in developing. But I don't know your full setup so you might need it.

You might want to try switching to [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) instead of sass. I switched over a year ago  and used postcss plugins that support any mixins or sass variables I needed at the time.

Comment: Am I right that it should be put after `watch: false`?   I just added it in there and ran `webpack` and the compile time was 81793ms which is just rediculous. I can;t switch to PostCSS for this project unfortunatley. The CSS also need to be separate files at all time in this project but in others I getcha and understand they don;t need to be. Any other ideas to speed things up as that didn't seem to make any difference. Sorry.

Comment: @rctneil is there a repo I can pull/fork from?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry I can't help. I think it is resolve-url-loader causing the slow down.

You can try turning on [debug and define the root](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader#options) directory. As it might be searching unnecessary folders.

```
use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  use: ["css-loader", { loader:"resolve-url-loader", options: { debug: true}
  }, "sass-loader?sourceMap"]
});
```

Comment: Using the debug option it showed several css assets where it was looking in hundreds of paths before successfully locating the files. Resolving that has brought compile from 85s to 15s!! Thankyou. Now the majority of CSS assets require looking in two paths before finding the file. Is there anything I can do to force it to just find it straightaway? My url() is url('../svgs/twitter--white--square.svg') .  This is relative to the .scss file. Is that correct? Or should it be to something else?

Comment: Got it. Got all the URL paths down to one path search and compile time is down to 12s. Much better but still could be faster. I now need to figure out why watch doesn't work and find a way to only get things to recompile when they've changed.

Comment: Good to hear. Without seeing the project structure I cannot really help much more. I tend to put any assets jpg/png/svg etc in a assets folder then refer to that in my css/sass files. Then use webpack loaders to deal with those files without having to deal with resolve-url-loader. If you could make a basic GitHub repo with your project setup and basic example of how you are using your sass files in it. I would happy to help you out.

Comment: Ok, I'll create a repo over the next few days and link to it here when ready. Thanks